# Golang 1.6.2 Won't Upgrade on OSX Sierra

Tags: macos, go, upgrade

I just upgraded to OSX Sierra from El Capitan. As such, I also need to upgrade my Golang compiler from 1.6.2 since it does not support Sierra.

I downloaded the latest 1.7.5 pkg installer and ran it, getting the prompt that it would remove previous versions of Go, and it said it was successful. But when I run `go version` it still says `go1.6.2 darwin/amd6`.

I have gone so far as to manually delete my `/usr/local/bin/go` directory and run the 1.7.5 installer again, but `go version` still says `go1.6.2 darwin/amd6`. I have also restarted my terminal window and even the full computer between attempts.

What is going wrong? How can I get my Go compiler to update?

Comment: which is the output of `type go`, and `go env`?

Comment: I lied. I deleted `usr/local/go`, but not `usr/local/bin/go`. I just deleted both directories and ran the package installer again. Now `go version` tells me I am on 1.7.5 as expected and it looks like everything works.

Comment: Recommendation for the future: take a look at [gvm](https://github.com/moovweb/gvm).  It works a lot like rvm or virtualenv for managing runtime versions, allowing hotswapping and easy version management for your Go runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was incorrect in my question. I actually deleted `usr/local/go`, not `usr/local/bin/go`. I went back and deleted both directories manually, then ran the 1.7.5 package installer again. After restarting my terminal window, `go version` now shows me I am on 1.7.5 and it appears to be running correctly when I compile my code.

Still interesting that the package installer did not do this automatically like it said it would. This could work as a solution if someone else is having the same problem.